# nodejs does not recognize optional chaining operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

My node version 12 does not recognize optional chaining operator. Sometimes the match is `null`. It complains about

> Unexpected token '.'

```
export function getDiscount(description) {
  return description.match(/\d+(\%|\s\bpercent\b)/)?.[0];
}
```

Do I need to set an flag or something?

It works here

```js
console.log(null?.[0])
```

Comment: Which version of Node.js 14? Perhaps it's relevant, I'm not sure.

Comment: @VLAZ oh wait. its actually `v12.16.3` i confused it with the version i have on my server

Comment: I think that's your problem...

Comment: @VLAZ i will download the latest version on my laptop that should fix it